# Magento upgrade version 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.3

Tags: magento-upgrade, version

How do I upgrade my site Magento version 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.3

Please give me suggestion how can I do this 
I take all backup file in an old version in site 
so how can I upgrade through a command line 
or manually give me suggestions fast.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.3 Version Upgrade Commands.

follow command.

1) First Go to Disable Cache & Compiler using Command.

-> Go to Shell Folder and run the command

Command --> php -f compiler.php clear

Command --> php -f compiler.php disable

2) touch maintenance.flag

3) rm -rf var/cache/ var/session/

4) php -f shell/compiler.php -- state  && php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable

5) chmod -R 777 .

6) chmod 550 ./mage

7) ./mage mage-setup .
   After this command, if you getting error Like "channel communication already exists" then run below command

8) ./mage channel-delete community

9) ./mage config-set preferred_state stable

10) ./mage sync

11) ./mage install https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

12) ./mage list-installed

13) ./mage list-upgrades

14) php shell/indexer.php reindexall

15) rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/

16) rm -rf var/cache/ var/session/

17) php -f shell/compiler.php -- enable

18) chmod -R 777 var media

19) chmod 550 ./mage

20) rm -f maintenance.flag

Comment: Hi
It's working for me .....
Thank you